# I can not edit my Main Menu

Tags: gnome, menu

When I right click on **Main Menu** and select **Edit Menus** nothing happens. I want to edit few of the menu items and I am stuck. How do I edit main menu now?

Comment: in a terminal - type "alacarte" - any error messages that you can report in your question?

Comment: @fossfreedom: when I wrote 'alacarte' in terminal it gave a permission denied error for ~/.config/menus/applications.menu. When I looked at the file I found that somehow whole ~/.config/menus directory was owned by root. chaning the owner to my self solved my problem. Thanks a lot. If you add your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Ta - comment converted to answer.  Well done binW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right Clicking the Menu and choosing the "Edit Menus" option runs the application called "alacarte"

You can run the application from the terminal window

i.e.

```
alacarte
```

The advantage of running the application this way, is that any errors during the startup of the application will be reported to you and possibly this could guide you on how to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can edit the menus by Going to System - > Preferences -> Main Menu .

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal and type this:

```
gksu env LC_ALL=C gmenu-simple-editor
```

If an error output, add to your message please.

Comment: This app is not longer exist in Ubuntu.