# How do I edit applications panel menu in Lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu, menu, editing, alacarte

Main menu (`alacarte`) cannot record changes as it should. Some time it does, but randomly and rarely.

Is this a bug?

This question is not a clone of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/q/42412/47206). In that case the Main menu would not open, in this case it does but changes are rarely recorded.

Comment: Have you tried [MenuLibre](http://www.smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/)? You can get it via Synaptic or the Ubuntu Software Center but not via the Lubuntu Software Center (the last time I looked).

Comment: Try to use the `locate` command or `find` command to search via terminal . Example: `locate "rc.xml"` . The file called **lubuntu-rc.xml**. I don't know if the file remains the same(name) at Lubuntu **12.10**

Comment: at the time of the question `menulibre` was not available for quantal: but meanwhile it is (as of 24.0ct.2012): http://ppa.launchpad.net/menulibre-dev/devel/ubuntu/dists/

Comment: Just use PCManFM->Go->Applications.
MenuLibre and Alacarte are derped.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- **[LXMenuEditor](http://lxmed.sourceforge.net/key=BMaC4WojdugD) (Main Menu Editor)**

Execute the `LXMenuEditor.jar` file (Java needed), and then use the program to add the same file to the main menu... (with no spaces in the path...)

- Java based
- Cannot edit the main categories (as `alacarte` would if it worked)
- Can open and edit .desktop files as text

[image]

[On youtube](http://youtu.be/OBjIbcwEd1U)

- [**Menulibre**](https://smdavis.us/projects/menulibre/) (as [vasa1](https://askubuntu.com/users/25656/vasa1) suggested in a comment) is a good solution, as it is available for Quantal 12.10 (it was not at the time of the question). See [this](http://www.smdavis.us/2012/06/26/ubuntu-app-showdown-menulibre/) and [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/220967/47206). But, just like LXMenuEditor (and unlike Alacarte), it cannot create/edit main categories.
- Considering **Alacarte in Lubuntu**: it deserves a try as far as it can edit/create main categories, but it's actions are indeed only randomly possible in 12.10 , and, as far as I can tell,  it doesn't work at all in 12.04. It has to be regarded at this point (version 0.13.2-2ubuntu4) as **unsuitable for LXDE/Lubuntu** (as it is made for Gnome). Please comment here if this is not the case or if it changes in a new version.  For a reason on why it does not work, see [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/160472/47206).

Answer (score 13):

If you want to edit menu entries, the program you want to use is `alacarte`. Do not waste your time in xml files. Alacarte is the best graphical menu editor for all gtk based menu systems.

```
sudo apt-get install alacarte
```

[image]

Note/update: alacarte (Main Menu editor) does not work in 12.04 or 12.10 Lubuntu

Answer (score 8):

The xml file `menu.xml` responsible for Lubuntu menu is located in`/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml`. You can edit the xml file there. But it is recommended to copy it in your home folder `~/.local/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml` and edit there.

The other two file involved in Lubuntu menu is :

- `/etc/xdg/lubuntu/menus/lxde-applications.menu`
- `/etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu`

Take a look at [this page](http://wiki.lxde.org/en/Main_Menu#Menu_Editor) about LXDE menus. There is also a Java application which can be used for editing LXDE menus. It called LXMED and can be found on [it's project page on sourceforge.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lxmed/)

Answer (score 6):

Using **PCManFM**

- Open PCManFM Select from Menu > Go > Applications
- **To Remove** : Right click on the icons and select Hide
- **To Add** : <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to show hidden entries then right click on the icons and select Unhide
- Run `lxpanctl restart` in the terminal

Done!

Answer (score 4):

You can do it this way:

- Go to `/home/username/.local/share`
- Create a folder named `applications`
- Create a file named `whatever.desktop`
- Edit it (with leafpad) putting something like this:

  ```
  [Desktop Entry]
  Type=Application
  Categories=Utility
  Name=My dear folder
  Icon=/usr/share/icons/gnome/48x48/places/folder.png
  Exec=pcmanfm /my_dear_folder
  ```
- Open a terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
- Run:

  ```
  lxpanelctl restart
  ```

Done!

NB: Inside the `whatever.desktop` file no blank lines should be placed.

Comment: The categories don't match the menu names, so check [this list](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/menu-spec/menu-spec-1.0.html#category-registry) for the available categories.

Answer (score 1):

The default menu entries are located in the `/usr/share/applications/` directory.
For example, the Chrome browser can be edited at `/usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop`
If an entry is also defined in the local `.local/share/applications/` directory then it overrides the default one.

Answer (score 0):

In 16.04 go to `-/.local/share/applications` and delete the offending item.
Then `openbox --restart`

Answer (score 0):

Command line simplification of [*saimischief*'s answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/651061/561230):

```
pcmanfm menu://applications && lxpanelctl restart
```

This will start up `pcmanfm` in the correct directory, and one can rename, copy, move, or delete menu items as needed.  After `pcmanfm` is closed, `lxpanelctl restart` will update the menu.

---

It's even possible to edit the *.desktop* configuration files that the menu items link to:

1. Right click on an item, for example `menu://applications/Internet/` pick *Firefox Web Browser*.
2. A little menu pops up, pick *Properties*, which starts a little *GUI*, and allows the user to change several things, like the title, the command line options *etc.*.

A text editor can be used for more fine-grained control of [*.desktop* configuration files](https://standards.freedesktop.org/desktop-entry-spec/desktop-entry-spec-latest.html):

1. Right click on an item, for example `menu://applications/Internet/` pick *Firefox Web Browser*.
2. A little menu pops up, pick *Open With*, and then select your preferred text editor from the list of programs.