# remove Cisco subfolder from lubuntu start menu

Tags: lubuntu, vpn, cisco

I know, that there is bunch of threads and blog posts dealing with this topic, but none of them could help me out with my attempts to remove the folder of the "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client" from my start menu.

I am currently using Lubuntu 14.04 and have to use the aforementioned client (please don't ask). In the start menu, there is the default folder "Internet", which contains some shortcuts to browser and so on as usual, as well as the subfolder "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client", which contains only the shortcut to the actual "Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client".

Obviously, it is annoying to have a subfolder with only one shortcut and I want to get rid of it. But I can't find the location that points to this subfolder!

It is not

```
/usr/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
~/.local/share/lubuntu/openbox/menu.xml
/etc/xdg/lubuntu/menus/lxde-applications.menu
/etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu
```

as pointed out [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196614/how-do-i-edit-the-menu-in-lubuntu), and also not

```
/etc/xdg/menus/lxde-applications.menu
~/.config/menus/lxde-applications.menu
~/.local/share/desktop-directories
```

as pointed out [here](https://lkubaski.wordpress.com/2012/11/02/adding-lxde-start-menu-sections/).

I have found the according `.directory` file at`/usr/share/desktop-directories/cisco-anyconnect.directory` and the according `.desktop` file at `/usr/share/applications/cisco-anyconnect.desktop`, but simply deleting the `.directory` file does not work, the folder stays in place (I did a `lxpanelctl restart` after every change).

Any further ideas are highly appreciated.

EDIT @DK Bose: This is another point that bothers me, this line is missing. Here is the full content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client
Comment=Connect to a private network using the Cisco Anyconnect Secure Mobility Client
Exec=/opt/cisco/anyconnect/bin/vpnui
Icon=/opt/cisco/anyconnect/pixmaps/vpnui48.png
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've found a solution. The key is the file `/etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/cisco-anyconnect.menu`, which is hard to find (at least it was to me), because the use of this folder seems to be rarely documented (none of the tutorials I've found mentioned it).

Anyway:

```
sudo -i    # avoid typing sudo every time
rm /etc/xdg/menus/applications-merged/cisco-anyconnect.menu    # delete file that connects the .directory and the .desktop file
rm /usr/share/desktop-directories/cisco-anyconnect.directory    # delete the directory
echo "Categories=Network" >> /usr/share/applications/cisco-anyconnect.desktop    # add category so the client is placed in the folder "Internet"
exit    # terminate sudo shell (important!)
```

However the `.menu`-file links to the files listed above, I've found a copy of the `.desktop`-file in `~/.local/share/applications/cisco-anyconnect.desktop` which seems to collide with the aforementioned one. This can simply be solved by `rm ~/.local/share/applications/cisco-anyconnect.desktop`.

Also, `lxpanelctl restart` was not sufficient to take the changes into effect, a system restart was necessary.