# Can't get app to come up using the link (or entry) in the start menu

Tags: 22.04, lubuntu, menu

I recently installed Mullvad browser on one of my copies of Lubuntu 22.04. However, when I click on the link (or entry) for it in the start menu, nothing happens. Yet, when I click on the icon located in my .local/share/applications folder, the browser comes up with no problems. How can I get the browser to come up using the link in the start menu? :-/

Thank you for your help, I appreciate it! :-)

[image: screenshot from 2024-03-01]

Comment: Maybe useful (*creating a desktop launcher*) is in the manual - https://manual.lubuntu.me/lts/5/5.2/desktop_icons.html

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add shortcuts under specific categories in your Lubuntu applications menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219811/how-to-add-shortcuts-under-specific-categories-in-your-lubuntu-applications-menu)

Comment: Thank you, guiverc, I appreciate your help but I'd like to use the entry in the start menu, if at all possible and Lord willing. :-)

Comment: You mention your release (22.04) but not if you've upgraded your LXQt version (using [Lubuntu backports](https://lubuntu.me/jammy-backports-22-04-3-lxqt-1-4/))... If you've upgraded your LXQt version, the following maybe heflpul - https://lxqt-project.org/blog/2022/06/18/menu-editing-in-lxqt/

Comment: Thank you again but I want to get the existing entry working. I've tried giving the entry "executable powers," so to speak, but to no avail. Is this a symlinks issue? If so, how do i fix that?